# Allowing specific actions for non signed-up users in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, local-storage

I am starting a little learning project that would involve the following scenario:

User enters the page, there is a counter on the page which is connected to real-time database on `firebase` he/she presses the button, counter goes up,  database is updated, but this user is not allowed to increase the counter anymore. Even when the app is closed and he/she opens it in couple of days.

The question is: is it possible to achieve something like this without explicitly login user in? So that on subsequent sessions the prohibition persists based on IP address or something. Maybe it could be achieved with local storage?

Thanks for any responses and ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing requires that you can identify the app instance: the specific installation of your app on a certain device. For Firebase the easiest way to do this is using [Firebase's anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth). This creates a unique identifier for the app instance, without requiring the user to enter any credentials.

Comment: As far as I understand this could also be applicable for the web? Sorry, didn’t make it explicit, that I am talking about web-app. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this applies for the web too. In fact, the link I provided is to the documentation for the web/JavaScript SDK.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept the answer, and check the documentation. Hope it will be a solution for my use-case.

Comment: Hey Frank, I’ve read anonymous login docs but I am still not sure, how could I achieve the type of behavior I am expecting. Could you please elaborate just a little bit, or link some resources where I can find the explanation? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You were asking for a way to identify a specific user/session without requiring the user to sign in. Within the Firebase platform, anonymous authentication does precisely that: it associates a UID with the app installation, so that the next time the app starts it identifies itself with the same UID.